# Magento 2 minicart translation issue on some browser

Tags: magento2, js-translation

I have Magento 2.2.5 website running successfully, but I am facing one serious issue on Minicart section and add to cart button. Everything get translated but on some browser like chrome and safari minicart and add to cart button are not translating. Can any one help me to fix this issue.

[Website URL](https://test385.derendo.com/)

[See here too](https://community.magento.com/t5/Welcome-to-the-Magento-Community/Magento-2-translation-issue-on-some-browser/m-p/103667)

[image: On Mozila Browser]

[image: On Chrome Browser]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all your JS-translations are not working, are you using a translation-pack for the DE translations?

Comment: Yes I am using all the translation. If JS-translations are not working then why all translations working fine on Mozila but not on Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the sites that have translation csv in their custom theme. I couldn't find the best solution for it or the reason behind it. I found a work around for it. You can activate inline translation and manually translate/override that button.

Go to admin->store->configuration->advanced->developer. In translate inline, set `enable for storefront` to yes. Save config and then flush cache.
Go back to your site store front and edit the translation for `add to cart button`. Then with the same path on admin set `enable for storefront` to no. Save config and flush cache.

This will fix the issue but there is a draw back in it. The translation for that button may break time to time when you deploying static content. One way to fix it is to flush `Static file cache` & then flush `Magento cache`.
Basically this is not the best fix for the issue but it is a workaround.

Comment: You have the same problem I mean on chrome browser minicart not translated and on Mozilla it translated?

Comment: well not exactly, when piece of translation breaks (like the `Add to cart` button) it is not translated in Chrome or Firefox.
But if it is just related to chrome, may be it is because of site data and caching of chrome.